# How to stretch my background using css in react ? (handle overflow)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

- Here when i am in my homepage the background renders just fine
- It completely covers everything (except navbar which is expected)

**What Breaks the css**

- I recieve and `render` alot of images in my page after making an `API` call
- So the div **does not** expand to cover the whole background but its `height` is the same as in the beginning basically an **overflow** occurs
- I do **NOT** want an additional scrollbar by setting overflow as `scroll`

**What i want to achieve**

- I want to tell my `div` somehow to react to the new rendered `items` and expand accordingly.

**Note**

Setting `height:auto; width:auto;` doesn't work either as it breaks some of my other `UI` components.

**App.css**

```
.App {
  background: grey;
  height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/UI/Navbar/Navbar'
import Body from './containers/Body/Body'
function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <div className = "App">
        <Body />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your div.App got re-render for each image
some how repaint is skipped for some pure dom element.

If you are sure about this thing,
Try to put a wrapper (let's say another div) instead of React.Fragment
and set its display to flex with flex-direction: column;

then put flex-grow: 1 to your div.App and flex-shrink: 0; to your Navbar (if your dom structure cause shrinking)

```css
.Wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* set layout viewport to anything that works for you*/
  height: 100%
}
.App {
  background: grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  /* this part can be based on you layout or replaced with flex-basis instead */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/UI/Navbar/Navbar'
import Body from './containers/Body/Body'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="Wrapper">
      <Navbar style={{ flexShrink: 0 }}/>
      <div 
        className="App" 
        key="Set to src of image if you want to force re-render for each image"
      >
        <Body />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Doesnt work :( guess i will have to store the number of images in my redux store and accordingly adjust my class name of the wrapping div around my body to increase or decrease the height ... although i feel bad to use hax everytime i face a problem .......